# Требует точку с запятой при создании метода

Tags: java

Простите за максимально тупой вопрос. Я только начал изучать Java, пытаюсь создать метод, но компилятор жалуется на пропущенную точку с запятой, её добавление ничего не меняет, хотя я и сам понимаю, что точки с запятой там не должно быть

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        void printHelloWorld *ВОТ ТУТ ТРЕБУЕТ ТОЧКУ С ЗАПЯТОЙ* {
            System.out.println("HelloWorld");
        }
    printHelloWorld()
    }
}
```

Comment: `()` забыли..... `<тип возвращаемого значение> <название> () { <тело> }`, т.е. `void printHelloWorld () { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь объявить один метод внутри другого. Объявляйте методы внутри класса.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private static void printHelloWorld () { //Объявляем отдельно
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        printHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор не всегда может догадаться, что именно программист хотел написать. Он видит синтаксически некорректную программу и показывает *приблизительное* место ошибки и исходя из синтаксиса языка, что возможно не так. И не всегда пишет правильно.

Тут скорее всего он трактует `void printHelloWorld` как объявление переменной типа такого:

```
int i;
```

а такое определение заканчивается точкой с запятой.

В чем можно быть уверенным, это что где-то рядом с местом, которое он показывает - ошибка. С опытом научитесь распознавать.

Собственно про саму ошибку уже ответили.